# My "i"variable is incremented and I do not know how

Tags: c

I am a beginner programmer and while practicing c-lang I came across a loop problem.

here is the code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <limits.h>
  #include <string.h>

    int main(void)
    {
    char s[5];
    int lim = 5;
    char c;
    int t;
    for (t=0;t<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF;++t)
    {
        
        s[t] =c;
        printf("%d\n",t);
    }
     printf("MY t got incremented and i do not know how: %d",t);
    s[t]='\0';
    
     
    printf("%c",s[0]);
    printf("%c",s[1]);
    printf("%c",s[2]);
    printf("%c",s[3]);
    printf("%c",s[4]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
      0
      1
      2
      3
      4
```

Why was variable `t` increased to 4?

If I input enough char's the max my `t` value gets is 3. My loop ends with `t` value being 3 but, after i exit the loop, my `t` is incremented to be 4. I do not know where this addition is happening. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Yes you are. `t == 4` is what exits the loop

Comment: You are printing `i` but there isn't any `int i` defined in the code. Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with complete code that demonstrates the problem. I recommend using copy/paste. If you are talking about `t`, it is incremented by `++t`. If the loop iterated 4 times (as shown by the output, then `t` is incremented 4 times, from `0` to `4`.

Comment: For future reference getchar() returns an "int" not a "char"...

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is `t < lim - 1`; when `t` is `3`, the condition looks like `3 < 4`. The loop goes one more time. Then at the end of the loop, `t` is incremented to `4` via `++t`. When `4`, `4 < 4` fails and then you exit the loop, but `t` will still be `4`.

I suggest you start with `lim` value of 0, then 1 then 2... so on and print the value of `t`. This will tell you what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! You are right, your `exit condition`, judging by the code you submitted, is always when t is **smaller** than **4**. In order to exit the loop, eventually `t` must get incremented to **4**. In *most cases*, any variable you use to exit a loop will always be larger,smaller or equal to the exit condition.

Should you want `t` to be the value right before you exit the loop, you must decrease it like so:

```
t--;
```

or

```
--t;
```